# How can I quickly locate the location of a word in R script in the R studio?

Tags: r

how can I quickly locate the location of the word  in R  script in  the R studio ? I mean I do not open the r script by using some txt-editor and search it.

Answer (score 0):

`Mac: cmd + f`,
`Windows: ctrl + f`